# How to display alternate file formats in save dialogue for macOS

Tags: swift, macos, save

I'm writing a document-based application for macOS in Swift 4, and I'm having trouble saving the document to different types.

The app has a custom file type that it uses to store its data in an easily accessible format, but it also needs to be able to export the data in plain .txt format for use with other applications. I have programmed all the functionality I need for this and set up an NSExportableTypes array for the native file type in the plist, but the 'Save As' dialogue still doesn't show the pop-up list to choose the file type you'd like to use and will only allow the native file type.

Anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: If you're using Save As shouldn't you set the `allowedFileTypes` attribute on NSSavePanel instead?

Comment: I haven’t overwrittenNSSavePanel, would I need to do that to accomplish this?

Comment: No you don't have to do that.